# Show hidden apps (⌘H) in Mission Control

Tags: macos, mission-control

In OS X 10.8.5 if I hide an app with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, it does not show in Mission Control until it has been revealed again via the app switcher or dock.

Is it possible to show windows for hidden apps in Mission Control?